# Update/remove text that is spread to different nodes

Tags: javascript

The title may not seem that self-explanatory, but the question is actually pretty simple. Imagine the following code:

```
<div class="line">
    Some text node here. <span>Some nodeType 3 here.</span> 
    More text here. <span>And here as well.</span>
</div>
```

Now, using javascript I'd like to delete the contents of the div. So something like:

```
function deleteContent(from, to) { 
    // Some code to execute here
}
```

and the result will be something like:

```
<div class="line">
    Some text node here. <span>Some nodeType</span>
</div>
```

So basically, in theory, it's like using the `slice` function `div.innerHTML.slice(from, to)` except that this would only work if there were no tags within the div. I've already thought about creating a text range and deleting the contents with deleteContent but I don't know if it is the simplest way to go. What are your suggestions?

PS: I'd like to have a code that is neat and logical.

**EDIT**

As a response to Felix: Yes, I treat from and to as two integers. And for whitespaces, in my application I'll have to understand each whitespace seperately. That is, `&nbsp;&nbsp;` are two characters.

Comment: `from` and `two` are numbers then? How do you treat the whitespace before `More text here.` or `Some text node here.`? Collapse into one, like HTML is doing it? Could you give a concrete example with actual input and expected output?

Comment: I actually didn't mean `&nbsp;` (although that's good to know as well). I meant if your text contains e.g. ``foo___bar`` (`_` is a space). HTML would display it as `foo_bar`. Do you consider all white spaces or not?

Comment: @FelixKling yes I'll treat it as foo___bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working on exactly this for my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library and I'm almost ready to release it. In the meantime, you can use something like the following that will work in most situations but has drawbacks:

- doesn't work in IE < 9
- doesn't take into account implicit line breaks from block elements and `<br>`s
- doesn't ignore invisible text, such as contents of `<script>` and `<style>` element or text inside elements with CSS `display` set to `none`
- doesn't collapse spaces as they would appear on the rendered page
- other subtleties

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nT28h/

Code:

```
function createRangeFromCharacterIndices(containerEl, start, end) {
    var charIndex = 0, range = document.createRange(), foundStart = false, stop = {};
    range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
    range.collapse(true);

    function traverseTextNodes(node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
            if (!foundStart && start >= charIndex && start <= nextCharIndex) {
                range.setStart(node, start - charIndex);
                foundStart = true;
            }
            if (foundStart && end >= charIndex && end <= nextCharIndex) {
                range.setEnd(node, end - charIndex);
                throw stop;
            }
            charIndex = nextCharIndex;
        } else {
            for (var i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; ++i) {
                traverseTextNodes(node.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        traverseTextNodes(containerEl);
    } catch (ex) {
        if (ex == stop) {
            return range;
        } else {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}

function deleteBetweenCharacterIndices(el, from, to) {
    var range = createRangeFromCharacterIndices(el, from, to);
    range.deleteContents();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Apparently using Range is the best way to go.

Comment: @SavasVedova: Yes, I definitely agree with that.

Comment: @TimDown is there any update for this that takes into account line breaks? Thanks

Comment: @RafaelDiaz: There's the TextRange module in Rangy 1.3, which I'm still bugfixing but essentially works. Demo: http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/textrange.html

Comment: @TimDown That demo doesn't seem to answer my question at all

Comment: @RafaelDiaz: I intended to link to the documentation as well: https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/TextRangeModule. In particular, see the Range methods `selectCharacters()` and `toCharacterRange()`. The demo uses selection-based versions of these.

Comment: I have tried to select the characters like this: 

     `var range = rangy.createRange();
     range.selectCharacters(el, from, to);`
But it's not selecting, I'm not sure if I'm using the library correctly