# How to add / insert / update text inside contenteditable div at a particular position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

The HTML code looks like this

```
<div id="txtarea" contenteditable="true">Some text</div>
```

I have to insert some new text based on some event at a particular position in the above div.
The event calls the function say updateDiv(txt, positon). For example it says
`updateDiv("more ",5);`

So the div should become be

```
<div id="txtarea" contenteditable="true">Some more text</div>
```

I tried a lot of javascript and jquery but nothing seem to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882890/jquery-insert-text-to-textarea

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: No, that question relates to textareas, not `contenteditable`.

Comment: **Inserting string at position x of another string**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364881/inserting-string-at-position-x-of-another-string

Comment: use DOM mutation observer. Google it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I did it:

```
var position = 5,
    txt = "more ";
var current = $("#txtarea").html();
//alert(current.substring(0, position))
var endVal = current.substring(position);
var newValue = current.substring(0, position) + txt + endVal;
$("#txtarea").html(newValue);​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwsRM/) displaying it 'in action'.

**Edit**: Updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwsRM/1/) with the approach listed in a comment above to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4364902/469643). Pretty slick!

Comment: but this moves the cursor position. Its `contenteditable` div

Comment: @MeetM; yes, wiping out the `html()` of the div will move the cursor position. You never mentioned what event was generating the need to insert text. Presumably you must be trying to bind to a keyboard event. But if you are inserting text into something while someone is typing, they might not like it.

Answer (score 3):

If the content of your editable `<div>` always consists of a single text node, this is relatively simple and you can use the code below.

```
var div = document.getElementById("txtarea");
var textNode = div.firstChild;
textNode.data = textNode.data.slice(0, 5) + "more " + textNode.data.slice(5);
```

Otherwise, you'll need to read about [DOM Ranges](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range) (note that they are not supported in IE < 9) and use something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10299622/96100) to create a range corresponding to character indices within the content and then use `insertNode()`.

```
var div = document.getElementById("txtarea");
var range = createRangeFromCharacterIndices(div, 5, 5);
range.insertNode(document.createTextNode("more "));
```

Comment: A contentEditable div with line breaks will always have more nodes in the form of <br>? How is it possible to have a single text node?

Comment: @RafaelDiaz: The code in the question has a contenteditable element with a single text node. In general, obviously it's unlikely that an application using contenteditable would be much use if it only allowed the user to edit a single text node with no formatting.

Answer (score 0):

use this function :

```
String.prototype.splice = function( position, newstring ) {
    return (this.slice(0,position) + newstring + this.slice(position));
};
```

and use this function as :

```
var oldstr=$('#txtarea').html();
var newstr='more';
var position = 5;
$('#txtarea').html(oldstr.splice(position , newstr);
```